# How can I efficiently solve $Ax$=$b$ given $A$ is symmetric and contains very small (even negative) eigenvalues using EIGEN

Tags: matrix, eigen, inverse-problem

Currently I am using the EIGEN C++ library to try to solve $x$ from the equation $Ax$ = $b$. One problem I encountered is that the matrix $A$ is a correlation matrix with size  > 5000 and can sometimes be rank deficient and have small, even negative eigenvalues. As a result of that, the matrix tends to have huge condition numbers 100~1000+.

Special properties of the matrix $A$ include: symmetric (because it is a correlation matrix) and the correlation decreases as the two entries get further away (e.g. $R_{1,2}$ > $R_{1,6}$).

The current way I used to solve the equation is to use the [truncated SVD method](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=FAQ#Is_there_a_method_to_compute_the_.28Moore-Penrose.29_pseudo_inverse_.3F) to obtain a pseudoinverse of $A$. I also tried to exploit the fact that the matrix is symmetric by using the [self-adjoint eigen solver](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SelfAdjointEigenSolver.html) instead of SVD which speed up the process considerably. However, it still remains rather slow and from what I read, people always said one should **NEVER EVER** try to solve the inverse whenever possible.

As a result of that, I wonder if there is anyway for one to speed up this process even further. I have read that one can use the QR method to obtain the pseudoinverse. My understanding is that for $A$ = $QR$, I can replace $R$ with $R_k$ the when the diagonal at $k$ is the last element bigger than a threshold and any subsequent row will be replaced by 0.

So, my question is: is this QR method correct? Or is there any method that can better solve this kind of equation?

Comment: How slow is too slow? How fast do you need it to be?

Comment: When using the SVD with matrix size > 3000, I have to wait for 3 days and still couldn't get a solution.
Now with the self-adjoint method, I can get a 500x5000 matrix done within an hour. 
The main problem is that it is not scalelable with the required time increases exponentially. I am just interested to see if, for example, whether if I can solve a 10000x10000 matrix within say, an hour

Comment: I am currently using multi-threading with roughly 12 threads. Also, I don't have access to graphic card, so I couldn't use CUDA...

Comment: It shouldn't take more than a few seconds to compute the SVD of a 3000 by 3000 matrix using any reasonably efficient linear algebra library.  Don't use the QR factorization without pivoting- it's not a stable rank revealing factorization.

Comment: The problem of SVD is that EIGEN use Jacobian SVD which is one of the slowest I think. So if it is the pivoting QR, it is ok? [e.g.][http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1ColPivHouseholderQR.html]

Comment: 1000 is not a particularly large condition number and I'm not sure what you mean by 1000+? Did you try the obvious choice in Eigen-- FullPivLU? It doesn't exploit symmetry, of course, but might be  faster than what you are doing now. You say the matrix might be rank sufficient-- i.e the solution doesn't exist. So, presumably, you need to detect this case and FullPivLU will do so.

Comment: Just for the record, @Sam, Octave (the MATLAB clone), presumably single-threaded using ATLAS for BLAS, on my MacBook Pro, can do the SVD of a 3000x3000 random matrix in 10 seconds. There is something wrong with your Eigen implementation, and you might want to ask on [the forums or IRC channel](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page#Get_support) for some help.

Comment: What is wrong with the implementation is that it is using the Jacobi SVD algorithm, which is slower than the normal bidiagonalization algorithms. Eigen only includes this algorithm for SVD (because it is easier to implement, I presume). Luckily OP is working with symmetric matrices here. In the symmetric case, an SVD is an eigendecomposition and a Schur factorization. So the solution is simple: **switch to SelfAdjointEigenSolver** and forget about SVD.

Comment: Yes, I am currently using the **SelfAdjointEigenSolver** and upon reading the manual, I found that it already used the QR decomposition to help solving it. I am not sure if there's any faster way to perform such decomposition.

Comment: @Sam There is a bit of confusion because there are two different things known as "QR" in numerical linear algebra; one is a [matrix factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) and one is an [algorithm to find eigenvalues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm). SelfAdjointEigenSolver uses the latter.

Comment: In any case, your question now becomes "is QR (with pivoting) better or worse than an SVD to find the rank of a matrix", and the universally acknowledged answer is that the SVD is better (there are extreme counterexamples in which QR does not identify the rank correctly). So, TL;DR: stick with SelfAdjointEigenSolver, if its performance is good enough for you, and forget about the other approach.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, ok, thank you very much. I was hoping that somehow there might be better algorithms so that I can decompose say a 400,000 x 400,000 matrix though I do understand it is rather unrealistic...

Comment: They are not direct decompositions, but there are other algorithms to solve large and sparse singular systems of equations. Look for https://web.stanford.edu/group/SOL/software/lsqr/ for instance. But we really should know more about your equation. Is $b$ (approximately) in the column space of $A$? How large is the nullspace of $A$? Do you have to perform some form of regularization to avoid the solution components related to small eigenvalues?

Comment: I am sorry if I don't understand column space and nullspace concept too well. I do however know that the range of $b$ should contain only small negative variables and will not be bigger than 1. I am currently trying to read something on the nullspace and column space to understand that... As for regularization, I do require to perform the truncated SVD method to regularize my matrix in order to solve the equation.

Comment: One thing to note about EIgen is that it relies heavily on compiler optimizations. Make sure you compile with -O3 (in gcc) or whatever flags you compiler uses. It can be up to 3 orders of magnitude faster. Stack Overflow has multiple Q's & A's on the matter.